# What is the difference in koi o shita, ochita, shimashita?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

I was looking for (I fell in love with you), but did find more than one option. Could you help?

あなたに恋をした
Anata ni koi o shita

私はあなたと恋におちた
Watashi wa anata to koi ni ochita

私はあなたに恋を しました
Watashi wa anata ni koi o shimashita

What is the difference and which should I use?

Comment: The pronunciation could be incorrect. I apologise in advance

Comment: した and しました are the same word in two different levels of politeness. Are you also asking for information about politeness levels? If so, then also including おちました, the polite version of おちた, might be appropriate. If not, then the third sentence is redundant to the first.

Answer (score 1):

する in 恋をする means "do". So I sense activeness in this phrase. We use 恋をする for both 片思い(one-way love) and 恋愛(relationship). Anyway since it has 'active' meaning, I make images from the phrase 恋をする, such as writing a letter to tell his/her the love, waiting for a response from him/her over smartphone, wasting time by thinking about him/her and so on.

恋に落ちる exactly means "fall in love". From the word 'fall' I sense 'irresistability'. Sometimes I also feel 'astray' or 'off the track' meaning from it. So I think it's basically not suitable for relationship between adorable students. It smells more dangerous.

私はあなたに恋をしました This is grammatically perfect but sounds too polite. To tell love, excessive politeness sounds awkward in colloquial communication. It sounds like reading a story. But I think it's good in writing.